# Stop React Google AutoComplete <input> component re-rendering but render everything else on selection

Tags: reactjs, react-component, react-google-maps

In React when I select anything from AutoComplete it re-renders the `Input` element, how can I stop it from re-rendering the `Input` only element but re-render everything else?

So far I have tried:

1. To use shouldComponentUpdate() but either I'm using this incorrectly or something else is not working: [How to stop the google map from re rendering and keeping just the values in input fields when marker is placed on different locations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54476519/how-to-stop-the-google-map-from-re-rendering-and-keeping-just-the-values-in-inpu)
2. And placing AutoComplete component separately from Class component as suggested here: https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/issues/220

Demo running here: https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-ride-5ht4o

Comment: changing the state keyword into your name or something else the data you set in your state dose not have to be in your state and it's better not to be in state for better performance.  and i guess some how if you separate the  autocomplete component from AsyncMap your problem be solved.

Comment: how would you know by separating it will fix it?

Answer (score 0):

From [`shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)` documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate):

> Note that returning false does not prevent child components from
>   re-rendering when their state changes.

that's the reason why `AutoCompleteTest` child component gets re-rendered in your example.

You could prevent both `GoogleMap` and `Autocomplete` components from re-rendering by organizing `Map` component this way:

```
function App() {
  const AsyncMap = withScriptjs(
    withGoogleMap(mapProps => {
      return (
        <div>
          <Map
            defaultZoom={15}
            defaultCenter={{ lat: 55.686757, lng: 21.157926 }}
          />
        </div>
      );
    })
  );

  return (
    <AsyncMap
      googleMapURL={MAPS_URL}
      loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
      containerElement={<div style={{ height: "200px" }} />}
      mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
    />
  );
}
```

where

```
class Map extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentPosition: props.defaultCenter
    };
    this.handlePlaceSelected = this.handlePlaceSelected.bind(this);
  }

  handlePlaceSelected(place, input) {
    this.setState({
      currentPosition: {
        lat: place.geometry.location.lat(),
        lng: place.geometry.location.lng()
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <GoogleMap
          defaultZoom={this.props.defaultZoom}
          defaultCenter={this.state.currentPosition}
          center={this.state.currentPosition}
        >
          <Marker position={this.state.currentPosition} />
        </GoogleMap>
        <Autocomplete
          style={{
            width: "90%",
            height: "40px",
            marginTop: "10px"
          }}
          onPlaceSelected={this.handlePlaceSelected}
          types={[]}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Note:

- `center` needs to be explicitly specified along with `defaultCenter`  property for `GoogleMap` component to update map center

[Here is a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-uigtmj)